# RadAjaxNamespace is not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, radajaxmanager, telerik-ajax

The application is using RadAjaxPanel tags. Browsing to my development machine I get the error "RadAjaxNamespace is not defined" in the browser debug console, but not when browsing to our production server. When viewing the difference between the rendered html on both, I find that on the dev machine with the error, the web resource script include for the rad ajax is not rendered. `(Tag <script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=...)`

It used to work before I did a machine re-install. What could cause the rad ajax control to not render the script include?

Using RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX 2013.1.220.40, RadAjax.Net2.dll 1.5.1.0

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are using an old version of Telerik controls (RadAjax dll in this case) in a combination with a more recent one. Is there any specific reason why you would need to use the old controls? If not, I would recommend that you remove that DLL from your project. You only need Telerik.Web.UI.DLL, Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.DLL and Telerik.Web.UI.Design (provided that you need to use the design-time). 
As far as I know, the old controls (RadControls for ASP.NET Classic or something like this) are no longer supported and may cause problems due to various reasons like browser and .net compatibility. Also, I'm not sure if you can rely on any form of integration between these two products.